# Can't add AMP Variable for Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, amp-html

I am using Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager for a website, I am trying to add a custom dimension for my AMP pages, I found solution for that
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164990?hl=en (Step 2) and for AMP pages I am using AMP variables as described here https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9205783?hl=en.

```html
<amp-analytics config="https://www.googletagmanager.com/amp.json?id=Tag Manager-XXXXXX;Tag Manager.url=SOURCE_URL" data-credentials="include">
  <script type="application/json ">
      {
          "vars" : {
              "type": "shoes",
              "color": "red"
          }
      }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

But after adding AMP variables on my page I get AMP error "Custom JavaScript is not allowed" and Tag manager does not capture my variables.

Comment: Do you have add <script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script> in your header?

Comment: Yes I added that as described here https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9205783?hl=en

Comment: And the console error shows on this line of code? It looks correct for me.

Comment: I find the problem, it was from space in <script type="application/json ">, I copied that from their documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spend many hours to find error reason, so I want to share it with other developers. I just remove extra space which I copied from their official page https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/9205783?hl=en, and it starts to work.

I just replace `<script type="application/json ">` with `<script type="application/json">`